# mySQL - Dont insert same data to a row in table, if exists

Tags: php, mysql

I have a members table. It includes these rows;

Name - Surname - Age - Friends

I have a script that adds name value (for ex: John) to "friends" row when someone add as friend. It adds the name to friends row.

```
$myname = ",John,"; // the adder
$name = ",Marry,"; // the person to be added as a friend

mysql_query("UPDATE members SET friends = CONCAT(friends, '".$myname."')     
WHERE name='".$name."'") or report();
```

However, I need to add if value doesnt exists. For example, if John is already in the "friend" row, it shouldnt add it.

What is the correct way to do it ?

Comment: Does your friends column look like `MarryJosephJacobHarry`? It seems that the concat you perform just joins all the names together, that makes it harder.

Comment: No, actually its like ,marry,,john,,tim, (question is updated now)

Comment: IMHO: No, is not the correct way, here you have a relation (* user - * friends) you should use another table to store friends in each row (by id) and a relational table users_friens or if friends are users too, make a relational table with id_user - id_friend or something like this. If you store like strings, you should search and do a lot of stuff that are too much low to perfom...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `where` clause:

```
UPDATE members
    SET friends = CONCAT(friends, '".$myname."')     
    WHERE name = '".$name."' AND
          find_in_set('".$myname."', friends) = 0;
```

Now having said that, let me try to convince you that this is a really bad database design.  You should have a `MemberFriends` table with one row per member and one row per friend.  That is the proper way to store this in a relational database.  It is called a junction table.

Comment: Let me tell you the whole script structure. It checks itself (members) every 2 seconds. Its because chat website. So if I have multiple tables like you said, it would be multiple check queries every 2 seconds and that would be more harsh.

Comment: Tried your way, it errors this "Can't use function return value in write context"

Comment: found the answer, you should use double "==" instead of "=", but now getting "Call to undefined function find_in_set()"

Comment: @user198989 . . . MySQL doesn't have a `==` operator.  The above is a *SQL* query for MySQL, not PHP code.

Comment: Oh gotcha. I need it in php, what should I change ? I am using it inside  mysql_query("");

Comment: @user198989 . . . The answer describes what the final result should be like (there was an extra double quote in it).

Comment: There is a strange thing. In my script, names are added as ",john," the find_in_set function doesnt worked for these, it only works when if names are used without ",". How can I fix it ?

Comment: @user198989 . . . Can you ask another question, detailing what the issue is?